# Vuforia with Vive Camera texture

Tags: camera, vuforia, htc-vive

I'd like to use Vuforia with HTC Vive camera texture.

To use this, I added CameraRig that provided by SteamVR and 
an Script that brings its CameraTexture.

Now, I can see forward through HTC Vive hdmount Camera and I applied Vuforia package.

but, evenif I project target Image, this program cannot found target. 
just show me camera texture.

here are images that reflect my state.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using a Texture2D with Vuforia (assuming you can) after loading it with the buffer from the camera and applying it to the texture:

https://medium.com/@dariony/about-mixed-reality-part-2-4a371f03d910